# What statistical test would be best for before and after comparisons of multiple similar groups?

Tags: anova, variance, biostatistics, blocking

I can't exactly give the problem I'm working on but I will give a sensible example of how it looks:

I have 4 groups of people: diabetes, depression, schizophrenia, dementia, notice how a person with dementia can also be depressed. They're all given the same treatment (blue pill). However, there are different number of subjects in the control and test group within each disease group.

They'll be tested with different scales before and after using the blue pill (diabetes - blood test, depression - individual survey, schizophrenia - individual survey and dementia - individual survey)

I'm thinking of using a one way ANOVA test (Kruskal-Wallis) but I'm not fully convinced since it requires independent measures and there are no ordinal levels of data collected.

So what test should I be using?